# How Does the Installer's Windows Detection Work?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I have several Windows 7 systems which I am trying to make dual-boot.  The first one I tried, about a year ago, went perfectly, with the installer detecting Windows and installing appropriately.  A couple of others since, no way.  I have tried all the advice found on line to no avail.  One manual installation got to the point where 18.10 would boot, but Grub was invisible.  After auto-downloading and installing a bazillion updates, that one went into an endless loop on bootup, and I could not find Grub at all.

If I knew what the Ubuntu installer looks for to find a Windows installation, I can likely fake it so that the installer works.  Anybody know?

Comment: Typo above:  "18.10" s\b "19.10"

Comment: This might be something that might help.  Also search for OS prober for more info.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup

Comment: If you have prepared Windows (turn off Fast Boot), your partitions, and the hardware (changing SSD from RAID to AHCI) properly, then no "fake it" should be necessary. Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you really tried everything, then please edit your question to provide more data about what you tried and exactly how it failed.

Comment: AHCI makes no difference.  I made an installation thumb drive and deleted the boot partition on it.  Installed Ubuntu to a previously-prepared partition, drilling through all the dire warnings about no EFI boot.  Then booted a GRUB repair disk to install GRUB, and everything works.  The only minor glitch is that GRUB sees two Windows installations, the "system" partition and the actual C: partition.  I can live with that.